# Strange behaviour inserting item into a realtime DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code in a simple web page; it is connecting the page to a firebase realtime database, to allow a user to add items to the database.

It is working as expected, preventing duplicates of items with the same URL.

But it behaves weirdly in the sense that even when a new item is entered (without being a duplicate), the alert "This URL has already been registered." still pops up. As if the function was called an extra time after the item has been written to the DB.

Can anybody see and explain why this happens?

```
<form id='adTF'>
  Name: <input id='name' type='text' maxlength=128 size=50 value='' required>
  <br/><br/>
  URL: <input id='url' type='text' maxlength=128 size=50 value='' required>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('adTF').addEventListener('submit',addItem)

  var dbReference = firebase.database().ref('ItemList');

  function addItem(event) {
    console.log('Entering addItem');
    event.preventDefault();

    const url = document.getElementById('url').value.trim(),
          name = document.getElementById('name').value.trim();

    dbReference.orderByChild("url").equalTo(url).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        alert('This URL has already been registered.')
      } else {
        // The URL is not in the DB, we insert it.
        let newItem = dbReference.push();
        newItem.set({url:url,name:name});
        document.getElementById('url').value = '';
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
      }
    });
  } /* End of addItem */
</script>
```

P.S.

By putting trace messages inside the *addItem* function, I can understand that the function itself is not called twice but it is only *snapshot.exists()* which is run twice.

Comment: Did you try something like `console.log(snapshot.exists())` yet? That should also show if the function is called more than once.

Comment: Yes and it is indeed call twice when an item is inserted. Why is it called twice?

Comment: Is the callback called twice? Or is `addItem` called twice? I can only guess but if it's the callback, maybe insertion triggers a 2nd `value` event?

Comment: I don't understand the question, for me addItem is the callback. So what do you mean by callback? In any case I know that snapshot.exists() is called twice when an item is inserted into the DB. Only once otherwise as expected.

Comment: I made an edit to the post, hoping it make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else happens to have the same issue. Here is the solution:

The line of code:

```
dbReference.orderByChild("url").equalTo(url).on("value", function(snapshot) {
```

must be changed to:

```
dbReference.orderByChild("url").equalTo(url).once("value", function(snapshot) {
```

After all, knowing the way `on` works, it is not a surprise. After inserting an item the DB was pulled again, saying that the item was found.